# Reported Wi-Fi speed wrong

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-router

I have an FTTC Internet connection connected to a Plusnet Router 2704N. This bottlenecks my LAN and WLAN speeds to 100 Mbps and my WAN speed to 80/20.

When my PC is connected via LAN / Ethernet:

1. Windows reports that I have a 100 Mbps connection.
   [image]
2. Speedtest.net reports download speed of ~60 Mbps and upload speed of ~15 Mbps upload. 
   [image]

However, when my PC is connected via WLAN / Wi-Fi:

1. Windows reports that I have a 130 Mbps connection.
   [image]
   [image]
2. Copying a single large file from the LAN via the WLAN to my PC transfers at  ~2.2 MBps (~16 Mbps).
   [image]
3. Speedtest.net reports download **and** upload speeds of ~13 Mbps. 
   [image]

So, why is Windows reporting the network connection speed correctly for LAN / Ethernet but incorrectly for WLAN / Wi-Fi? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: There is a big different between the connections speed to the WAP and the throughput to the WAP, but there is a _huge_ difference between what your connection speed to the WAP and the throughput you can get across the Internet.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the netsh/wifi status screens show the *negotiated connection speed* and may not be subsequently updated beyond that. So if the negotiation phase starts high, and there are transmission errors etc, it may drop down the speed for reliability, but it may not update the number for the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Windows calculates the Wi-Fi speed never really translates down to the actual transfer rate. However, since you are seeing some big difference here, I suggest the following:

1) Try switching between 20 and 40 Mhz.

2) Investigate possible sources of EM interference.

3) Try moving closer to the access point.

In case these don't work, it is most likely a problem with either the network card or the access point.